# How to retrieve Posted file in create action of another entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am in trouble with a posted file related to an entity, I can see the posted file in the request, but if I add the httppostedfile as action parameter it will be null... what should I do to manage this case?

**NewsArticle model:**

```
public class NewsArticle
  {
    public string Title{get; set;}

    public int ID{get; set;}

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }

    //other stuff

  }
```

**where the field Image is:**

*the related entity will be created in the newarticlecontroller*

```
public class Image
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Subtitle { get; set; }

  }
```

**detail of view**

```
    @model GatorsWebSite.NewsArticle

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "NewsArticles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/forma-data" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>NewsArticle</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ckHolder" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Image)
      </div>
    </div>


    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuthorID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>*@

    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Published, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Published)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Published, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ckEditor")

  <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace("@Html.IdFor(m => m.Body)", {});
  </script>
}
```

**Controller action:**

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Body,SubTitle,Published,Image")]NewsArticle newsArticle )// here I don't know how to manage the posted file
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        newsArticle.Date = DateTime.Now;
        newsArticle.AuthorID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        newsArticle.Body = newsArticle.Body;
        _repository.Add(newsArticle);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      return View(newsArticle);
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am new to MVC so obviously I have to pay the tax, btw this is what I have done to solve this problem:

I have created a ViewModel to host the aggregated data of the view:

```
public class NewsArticleViewModel
  {
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public string AuthorID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public bool Published { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
  }
```

then I have changed the signature of the control action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Body,SubTitle,Published,ImageUpload")]GatorsWebSite.ViewModels.NewsArticleViewModel newsArticle)
```

then I have corrected a typo in the form declaration :)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "NewsArticles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

...and then I have changed the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUpload, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageUpload, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ImageUpload)
      </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And what if you put input file in your form like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="newsimage">Select news image:</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input id="newsimage" type="file" name="newsimage"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and post action will be:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Body,SubTitle,Published,Image")]NewsArticle newsArticle )// here I don't know how to manage the posted file
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    string ImageUrl="";
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
       if (Request.Files[i].FileName!="")
       {
           string UrlFile = Server.MapPath("~/newsimagefolderpath/") + FileName;
           Request.Files[i].SaveAs(UrlFile);
           ImageUrl = UrlFile;
       }
    }
    newsArticle.Date = DateTime.Now;
    newsArticle.URL = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageUrl) ? "defaultimagepath" : ImageUrl;
    newsArticle.AuthorID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    newsArticle.Body = newsArticle.Body;
    _repository.Add(newsArticle);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(newsArticle);
}
```